# How to invoke step functions parallely?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I have a list of 1000 items, so there will be 1000 step function running concurrently, one for each item. What's the fastest way to trigger this? (Using SQS or AWS lambda) ?

Comment: Please expand the question.
Are you trying to do this via the CLI? Console? An SDK? What language do you want to use?

Comment: @Uberhumus I have a step function setup which does preprocessing and inference for a data item. Now, I need to do this process on the entire dataset(over 10000 items). One way is to invoke step function parallelly for each input. So wanted to know how to do this? Or is there a better alternative to this approach?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly invoke Step function from SQS at the moment. You will have to use Lambda to trigger the Step functions. Beware of the [API action throttling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/limits.html#service-limits-api-action-throttling) of the Step function if you use a standard workflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a step function that has a [Map State](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-map-state.html) which will invoke your step step function [asynchronously](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-stepfunctions.html). So you just have to provide the list of items you need to process without having to wait for each execution to finish.

If you want to monitor the step function executions status, add an [EventBridge/Cloudwatch Event Rule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/cw-events.html).

You can use Lambda function, API gateway or Cloudwatch Event Rule to trigger this.